# SVN Prevent Files on Branch from Changes

Tags: svn, deployment, branch, branching-and-merging, collaboration

I'm trying to develop a branching structure in a project where we have release branches for each environment we release to (QA, Staging, Production). I have created these 3 branches with their environment-specific files/code. My plan is to merge in changes from the development trunk to these release branches, but I don't want to overwrite the environment-specific files/code. Can I simply 'lock' these files to prevent them from being updated when I do a merge into the release branch?

Possibly there's a better scenario for our release workflow out there... please let me know if I'm on the wrong track.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I don't want to say you're on the wrong track, but I would suggest you re-think.  Merging takes time and is an opportunity to introduce errors.  I think you'd be better served to build your release one time and promote it through dev/test/stage and finally production.

This will also make it much easier to track changes and file defects.

You didn't mention what language/tooling/platform you're using... This is going to take some doing to abstract the configs out of the release - or build configs for all environments during the initial build and configure the deployment/install to use the appropriate configs for the current environment.

Now to answer your question directly - there isn't a good way to 'lock' the files, when you do a merge.  You could do this with path based authorization or a hook script that would prevent users from checking them in... This would require them to revert affected files before committing. which may seem to work, but it's only a matter of time until a new config element is added on trunk and you actually want to merge it to the test branch.